# Angularjs selecting class return constructor instead of array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I using angularjs and i would like to do what i do in JQuery like this

```
var b=$(".brands");
console.log(b);
//this normally return array of elements
```

Ps. the elements are created by ng-repeat

When i run this using angular i receive this constructor no matter where or how i change my code

```
[prevObject: v.fn.v.init[1], context: document, selector: ".brands", constructor: function, init: function…]
```

I tried using angular.element i tried using it in the page it self and i tried with $scope and with out. its always the same result

Comment: When you get a log like that it usually means it's empty, ie there was no elements with class `brands` (you can check the length, ie `b.length`). Since you are trying to select elements that are created by an ng-repeat you are probably calling the log function before the ng-repeat has been processed.

Comment: yes that is the exact case but how can make it load after the ng-repeat

Comment: @PatrickEvans it did work repeating the steps i have done before by calling it with settimeout you can post it as answer if you want